# Print a web View in MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I have a web view where the user has an option to preview and print it on click of a button , In xamarin.forms we used Print Manager and Print Document Adapter to achieve this but the same does not seem to be working in MAUI , I checked the docs and there were no mention of the same !

Comment: The Print Manager and Print Document Adapter you mentioned are Android native codes. Have you tried using [Invoke platform code in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0) to call the API of the Android platform？

Comment: @ Sean - I tried the same but i was not able to invoke Print Manager from MAUI where as i was able to do it easily from Xamarin.Forms

Comment: You can firstly create a class and let it inherit `MauiAppCompatActivity`, and override the `onCreate` method in the class, then create a static class in the Platform/Android file that implements the method.